# Google Script that deletes Google Sheets Row if first 10 Columns are Duplicated

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a script that will search columns A:J within a row and if any other rows have those same columns, it will delete the new entire row.

I have a spreadsheet that has data importing rows into the spreadsheet into columns A to J.  We then manually input text into columns K to P.

If new data imports and matches those first 9 columns, we need to simply delete that new row and keep the existing one.  I found this script online that works perfectly, except it's not looking for a range of columns.  Rather, it's looking at the entire row

```
// [START apps_script_sheets_remove_duplicates]
/**
 * Removes duplicate rows from the current sheet.
 */
function removeDuplicates() {
 
  // [START apps_script_sheets_sheet]
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // [END apps_script_sheets_sheet]
 
  // [START apps_script_sheets_new_data]
  var newData = [];
  // [END apps_script_sheets_new_data]

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (j in newData) {
      if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
  
    // [START apps_script_sheets_duplicate]
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
    // [END apps_script_sheets_duplicate]
  }
  
  // [START apps_script_sheets_clear]
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  // [END apps_script_sheets_clear]

}
// [END apps_script_sheets_remove_duplicates]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[Reference:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var row = data[i].slice(0,10);
```

So perhaps this will work for you:

```
for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var r10=row.slice(0,10);
    var duplicate = false;
    for (j in newData) {
      if (r10.join() == newData[j].join()) {
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }

    // [START apps_script_sheets_duplicate]
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(r10);
    }
    // [END apps_script_sheets_duplicate]
  }
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work.  I also incorrectly stated 9 columns when it's actually 10 columns that continue to import.  I'm assuming i'm supposed to replace "var row = data[i];" with your code edit?

When I do that, it deletes all the data in columns K - P.

Comment: Well, the slice will return the an array with the selected items without affecting data[i].  This is just an idea.  Use it however you wish.

Comment: I appreciate your help, unfortunately I have no idea what I'm doing!

Comment: I made a small change to the answer perhaps that will help.  I often do things when I have no idea what I'm doing.